# Get boolean result whether table exists or not

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I don't want to commit a SQL request. I just want to known whether a specific table exists in data base or not, similar to the following pseudo statement:

```
IF EXISTS TABLE mytablename RETURN TRUE ELSE FALSE
```

How can I do this? I found several examples on how to modify a table if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's MySQL

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as I assumed you meant SQL Server.

Comment: @PAX . . . MySQL supports the `information_schema` tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends highly on the database, but this will work in many:

```
if exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'mytablename')
```

(You might want to add additional conditions for the database/schema name.)

Although `information_schema` is supported in several databases, other databases might use `all_tabs` (Oracle) or some other table/view.

And, if you want a query that returns this value, use:

```
select max(case when table_name = 'mytablename' then 1 else 0 end) as TableExists
from information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: I get following error message: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'geolocati' at line 1`

Comment: @PAX . . . MySQL only supports the `if` inside stored programs (stored procedures, functions, and the like).  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html.  You can use the second query to return a value for use.

Comment: It's also important to add the name of the data base (`'dataBaseName'`) which contains the table to the constraint. Otherwise, you detect a MySQL table if it has the same name: `SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN table_name = 'searchedTableName' AND table_schema = 'dataBaseName' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TableExists
FROM information_schema.tables`

Comment: @PAX thanks I just verified your expression with mysql 5.7 through nim-lang mysql module's `db.exec` function, using `?` parameters in place of directly names. and it works. helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Try this Proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoesTableExist (@TableName NVARCHAR(100))
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = @TableName)
        SELECT 1
    ELSE
        SELECT 0  
END
```